# Desktop icons disappearing while changing desktops on Sierra

Tags: macos, icon, desktop

There is a new "Reduce Motion" on macOS Sierra. If you turn that on and swipe to change desktops, I noticed that when you start swiping, all my desktop icons completely disappear and I only reappear when I've completely switched to the next desktop.

This is extremely annoying, as I change desktops quite a lot and despise the way the icons keep flashing when changing desktops (after all, I enabled the option in order to reduce the visual effects on the screen). Does anyone know how I can disable this?

Comment: Reduce Motion removed motion, not visual effects.

Comment: So you're saying you don't experience this problem?

Comment: It is a feature. Whats wrong? do you mean the apps in your launchpad or your file icons on your desktop? vague much.